# look for words on html with python

Tags: php, python, html, python-3.x

im trying to make a python3 script that looks for words say like "ArduinoON" etc on a web page. but its not going that good. I know how to do it with php but not with python. here is how i did it with php and how im trying to do it with python.

Here is how i did it in php.

```
    <?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://192.168.0.200:9090');
$regex = '/Switch1On/';

if (preg_match($regex, $data)) {
   echo '<font color="green">on</font>';
} else {
   echo '<font color="red">off</font>';
}
?>
```

My python code

```
 import urllib.request

x = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.0.200:9090/')
if "ArduinoOn" in x:
     print ("True")
```

Could any one help me?

Comment: Not really related to php since you're trying to do it in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a text string in the html page, you can use Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module. This is probably the easiest way to do it.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://192.168.0.200:9090/')
if "ArduinoOn" in r.text:
    print ('True')
```

Comment: im getting an error.   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xzenon\Desktop\html\pyscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: @Danieldarko I added a link in my post to the `requests` page where you can find instructions on how to install the module.

Comment: @Danieldarko Great. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) the `urllib.request.urlopen` returns a `http.client.HTTPResponse` object. So if you want to get the content of the page you should read it:

```
x = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.0.200:9090/')
if 'Arduino On' in x.read():
    print 'True'
```

Hope this helps.